# Google Apps Engine domain ID sync

Tags: sync, email, gmail, google

My college offers all students a gmail inbox on a domain ABC hosted via the Google Apps Engine. If my name is XYZ, my email ID is XYZ@ABC.ac.in

On a web browser, I simply use the Gmail login page to check my email. I am unable to set it up on my phone however. How can I sync my email on my phone?

I have a Nokia Lumia 520, Windows 8.1. Please leave a comment if this requires me to provide more details.

I have already tried using a simple Google account. Doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried adding the account as an Exchange account or 'other account' (IMAP or POP) in Settings > Email+Accounts?

Comment: What's stopping you from setting this up as a Google account?

Comment: -NeilTurner I do not know my SMTP server name in this case.
@RowlandShaw I am redirected to my account in a browser where I'm supposed to grant permissions to windows phone. Clicking on accept takes me back, this time the mailbox in Accounts+Settings says 'Attention is required' to provide permissions. Apparently, the providing permission part isn't going through.

Comment: With Google Apps, you use Google to send email - you can follow their setup instructions to get the settings (SMTP host address, port, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Settings-> email & accounts ->add an account -> advance setup

enter you email address < abc@xyz.com > and password

Select "Exchange ActiveSync"

Domain: xyz.com   --- i.e. address after '@' in your email address.----

Server: m.google.com

Cheers!